# Simplest Non-trivial exmaple from combinatorics

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinatorial-proofs

I'm listening to a lecture on probability and this expression comes up $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$ and it supposedly denotes the number of ways to put $k$ indistinguishable particles into $n$ distinguishable boxes but in an example where the instructor sets $n=2$, he then states the answer becomes
$\binom{k+1}{k}.$ I just need some logical narrative to understand how $2$ went missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that $2+k-1=k+1.$

Comment: Your notation is incorrect: you should be using parentheses, not square brackets. $\binom{n}k$ and $n\brack k$ mean two different things.

Comment: @mfl Thanks, that makes sense

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Noted, I'm just having trouble with the formatting

Comment: To get $\binom{m}{n}$ write \binom{m}{n} between $'s.